# deregistering events using controllerAs in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I tried controllerAs today and now my $scope.on is failing.

```
// old working code
$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
  deRegisterMouse();
});

// new code
var self = this;
self.$on('$destroy', function() {
  deRegisterMouse();
});
```

and it's failing with this error

```
TypeError: self.$on is not a function
```

Comment: Even with the controllerAs syntex, you still need to inject and use $scope when you want to use $on, $broadcast, $eval, etc...